# Django "manual" uploaded files doesn't take upload_to in account

Tags: django, file, file-upload, upload

I'm doing a migration from an old site to a new one, and this includes moving a lot of logos/images/PDFs etc around. On the old site I'm exporting these using a base64 encode, and I base 64 decode them on the new site. So far, so good. Everything seemed to just work.

But, for some reason the files ended up in my MEDIA_ROOT instead of in MEDIA_ROOT/. So this means there are a few thousand files in my MEDIA_ROOT, not good.

A bit of code:

```
ntf = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
ntf.write(base64.standard_b64decode(obj['logo']))
ntf.flush()
c.logo.save('photo-{0}.img'.format(c.id), File(ntf))
```

In this case, `c` is a Django model instance, and `logo` is an ImageField. The definition of the Django model `c`:

```
class C(models.Model):
    def file_path(self, filename=None):
        return (format(self.id).join(['c_obj', '.jpg'])).lower()

    name = models.CharField(_(u'name'), max_length=150)
    logo = models.ImageField(_(u'logo'), upload_to=file_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

Anyone who can tell me what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `file_path` function is not returning a directory name. It is returning 'c_obj13.jpg' (when `self.id` is 13). Because of this, there is no directory (note the absence of a directory seperator).